# Use of MuPad code into mathematica

Tags: import

Does somebody have experiences so as to transform a MuPad code into a notebook into *Mathematica*? I would like to export equations written in MuPad to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Mupad code is pretty much Maple code for the most part. I use Maple differential equations code as is inside Mupad notebook all the time. See this for some information on Maple/Mathematica code conversions. [how-can-i-transfer-mathematical-expressions-between-mathematica-and-maple](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31804/how-can-i-transfer-mathematical-expressions-between-mathematica-and-maple) If you have specific mupad code which does not run in Maple as is, then only choice I know about is manual conversion.

Comment: Someone has nominated this for reopening.  Is there a reason why?  (I do not know enough to determine whether or not it is a duplicate, and I don't have access the software to check answers.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I wrote about this in the chatroom.  I might be wrong, but I don't see how the answers below the other question really solve this.  MuPad code might look very similar to Maple code, but all those answers rely on specific Maple functionality that is not in MuPad!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Also, MuPad is just not Maple.  Even if *some* answers apply to both, MuPad really does deserve its own question.  E.g. if someone writes a packages to translate to/from MuPad, give them a chance to post it somewhere. It won't fit under the Maple question.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you very much for the explanation.