# How to import a Maple worksheet into Mathematica?

Tags: import, maple

I have Maple worksheet files (*.mw) from Maple 10-12 and I would like to import them in Mathematica 11. I have no access to Maple anymore. The worksheet files are XML based but not easily readable. Even a partial import would be better than nothing.

I tried the Mathematica Import command but it just imports the XML as text and the help does not indicate that Mathematica would be able to import Maple worksheets.

There is a conference proceeding about [From Maple 9 Worksheets to Mathematica Notebooks: An Almost Automatic Converter in Mathematica](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5397/) which seems to do what I want but I cannot find any related available code/tool.

There is a question on this StackExchange about [transferring mathematical expressions between Mathematica and Maple](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31804/how-can-i-transfer-mathematical-expressions-between-mathematica-and-maple) but the answers assume that access to Maple is still available, which is not the case for me.

Is it possible and if so how?

Comment: If you have an example file that you can make accessible, perhaps via GitHub, then it’ll be easier to help. Mathematica can certainly manipulate XML and many people have worked on XML to Cell conversions.